# Really need some help in WebView

Tags: android, video, android-webview

Why can not I normally play the video from the site.I am trying with `Webview`. When did in `VideoView`, video works, but not as much as I need (no scroll bar). Therefore I'm trying with `WebView`. This code shows me the video but does not play it. When I insert a link to a site that I need, I see a white screen. Tested on the phone as well. In `manifest.xml` I have given internet permissions.

```
wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        wv.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
        wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        String html = "<iframe width='420' height='345' src='http://m.ochepyatki.ru/video.php?vkey=be38112&f=11395221100' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>";
        wv.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.MyParserIP"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
        <activity android:name="MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

does not work

Answer (score 1):

Can you Check you android `Manifest.xml` that you added

`android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in application tag. if you do not added then added this in android `manifest.xml`.

OR

You can do this Method in activity.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
        webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```